# Why does the conditional care about the execution code despite not returning true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have this code conditionally displaying the project's title if we're in a view that has the `@project` instance variable:

```
<title>My app <%= "- " + @project.title if @project.present? %></title>
```

But it gives me an error with the following message: "can't convert nil into String", i.e. it tries to execute my string concatenation despite the conditional statement being false.

Why does it even bother?

Comment: I am sure `@project.title` is `nil`.. And you can't do `"stritng" + nil`.. Because [`String#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-2B) method expects only string arguments.

Comment: Yes I know, `@project.title` *is* `nil`. But why does ruby care about what's in the execution code when it's not going to execute it anyway?

Comment: Just for debugging do `@project.present? == true` instead of `"- " + @project.title if @project.present?`... see what does it print. I am sure `@project.present?` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check if a project is present

```
@project.present?
```

but you don't check if the value of its `title` property is set. When `title` is `nil`, the following concatenation

```
"- " + @project.title
```

will fail with the `can't convert nil into String` error because you are effectively trying to concatenate

```
"- " + nil
```

that are two different types. You must deal with this case explicitly or use nil-to-string casting by using the interpolation

```
<%= "- #{@project.title}" if @project.present? %>
```

Moreover, beware of precedences. Embedding if conditions in that way with a print, may lead to obscure bugs caused by evaluation precedence.